# What kind of automatic type conversion is happening when calling std::filesystem::exists with a std::string?

Tags: c++

According to [this](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/exists), `std::filesystem::exists` takes a `std::filesystem::file_status` or a `const std::filesystem::path&`. However, the following code works by passing in a simple `std::string`:

```
string filename;
getline(cin, filename);

if (std::filesystem::exists(filename)) {
    cout << "Exists" << endl;
}
```

How does this work? I am less interested specifically in the `std::filesystem` API, and more generally in the C++ mechanism that allows this.

I have read about implicit conversions. `std::string` could implement `operator std::filesystem::path` to be automatically convertible to a `path`. However it doesn't seem likely to be the case, because `std::string` is a highly general purpose class.

So what is going on here behind the scenes?

Comment: Just a constructor that takes `std::string` is invoked. A constructor may be marked as `explicit` in your class, thus making such implicit magic impossible, you'd have to call this constructor on your own before passing an object

Comment: Have you looked at constructors of `std::filesystem::path`? Which kind of implicit conversions do they provide?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`std::filesystem::path` has a [constructor that takes a `path::string_type` which `std::string` falls under](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/path/path). It is not marked as `explicit`, so it is allowed to be used here for an implicit construction.

Comment: Actually, the constructor is taking a `string_type`. And I think this is point that should be more clear.

Comment: @Gupta in this case, the `path::string_type` is just an alias for `std::string`

Comment: @RemyLebeau I know. But I think this ambiguity (`path::string_type` is just an alias for `std::string`) is the reason that we have such a Q. I just proposed to @Sombrero to make this remark cleaner.

Comment: @Gupta Done friend

Answer (score -1):

> more generally in the C++ mechanism that allows this.
>
> what is going on here behind the scenes?

The mechanisms is called [Implicit conversion](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/implicit_conversion) .